# jFrame about combo box

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jcombobox

I would like to ask a question about combobox as I mentioned a little bit in title. I want to make 2 comboboxes which one of them contains departure cities, the other one contains arrival cities.

For example:

We have got destinations as New York , Paris and Dubai. So when I choose New York in departure I don't want to see New York in other combo box (as arrival).  How can I do these ?

```
JComboBox Departure = new JComboBox();
Departure.setBounds(31, 58, 28, 20);
contentPane.add(Departure);

JComboBox Arrival = new JComboBox();
Arrival.setBounds(114, 58, 28, 20);
contentPane.add(Arrival);`
```

Comment: when you select new york from one JComboBox then you can remove it from other JCombobox.

Comment: 1) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use it consistently. 2) ***Use layouts.***  (Or expect me to get terse re. your next 4 questions about "why my GUI is SNAFU?".)

Comment: What is the `JFrame` tag doing here, and in the title ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this

```
 for(int i = 0; i < Departure.getItemCount(); i++){
      if(Departure.getItemAt(i).equals(Departure.getSelectedItem())){
         Arrival.removeItemAt(i):

   }
}
```

Comment: It works but it does it for first value. It doesn't do it dynamically. I put it inside an mouse Listener but it didn't do it correctly

Comment: I think you use departure.addActionListener() and place this code in actionPerformed().